# Actual syntax for procedure

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, stored-procedures

ERROR:  query has no destination for result data 
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead. CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function dataret() line 4 at SQL statement SQL state: 42601

I have written procedure code in postgreSQl 11. But while calling the procedure it is giving this error..

```
create or replace procedure dataret()
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
begin
select * from public.score;
end $$;
```

I expect output to retrieve all columns from score table but i am getting this error.

Comment: Try the example in the Manual and then work from there... https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createprocedure.html

Comment: You're getting the error because you're using a SELECT and the results have no where to go. If you wanted to perform some query and discard the results, you need to use the keyword PERFORM in place of SELECT. a_horse_with_no_name is correct, you want a function but you'll need to have a RETURN QUERY or RETURN NEXT before your SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a result use a function, not a procedure.

And you don't need PL/pgSQL for that either, a SQL function will be much more efficient:

```
create or replace function dataret()
  returns setof public.score
  language sql
as $$
select * from public.score;
$$;
```

Then use:

```
select *
from dataret();
```

Comment: But I want to write procedure to retrieve all columns from table 'score'. How should i do it in POSTGRESQL 11 ....!!! Is there any way to do that.. Please share it.

Comment: @user11044097: a procedure is the wrong thing if you want to return data from it. A function is the correct thing to use.